# Flutter, How do I default an RxBool variable to a value from Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, get

How do I default Rxbool variable `RxBool isVegan = false.obs;` to use a user value from firebase instead of false.

`preferences_controller.dart`

```
class PreferencesController extends GetxController {
  static PreferencesController get instance => Get.find();

  final userController = UserController.instance;
  final userRepository = Get.put(UserRepository());
  RxBool isVegan = false.obs;
  RxBool isDairyFree = false.obs;
  GlobalKey<FormState> updateVeganFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  GlobalKey<FormState> updateDairyFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // init user data when home appears
  @override
  void onInit() {
    initializePreferences();
    super.onInit();
  }

  // fetch user record
  Future<void> initializePreferences() async {
    isVegan.value =
        userController.user.value.preferences['Diet']['IsVegan'] ?? false;
    isDairyFree.value =
        userController.user.value.preferences['Diet']['IsDairyFree'] ?? false;

  void saveVegan(bool? value) {
    isVegan.value = value ?? false;
  }

  void saveDairy(bool? value) {
    isDairyFree.value = value ?? false;
  }

  Future<void> updatePreferences(int redirect) async {
    try {
      // here check for the integer value and navigate to the next screen
      switch (redirect) {
        case 0:
          // form validation
          if (!updateVeganFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            updateVeganFormKey.currentState!.save();
            return;
          }

          if (!updateDairyFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            updateDairyFormKey.currentState!.save();
            return;
          }

          Map<String, dynamic> Diet = {
            'Diet': {
              'IsVegan': isVegan.value,
              'IsDairyFree': isDairyFree.value,
            },
          };

          // Update the 'isVegan' field within the 'Diet' map
          Diet['Diet']['IsVegan'] = isVegan.value;
          Diet['Diet']['IsDairyFree'] = isDairyFree.value;

          // Create the data to update in Firestore
          Map<String, dynamic> dietData = {
            'Preferences': {
              'Allergy': {
                'IsEgg': userController.user.value.preferences['Allergy']
                    ?['IsEgg'],
                'IsNut': userController.user.value.preferences['Allergy']
                    ?['IsNut'],
              },
              'Diet': {
                'IsVegan': isVegan.value,
                'IsDairyFree': isDairyFree.value,
              },
            },
          };
          await userRepository.updateSingleField(dietData);

          // update the rx user value
          userController.user.value.preferences['IsVegan'] = isVegan.value;
          userController.user.update((user) {
            user?.preferences['Diet'] ??= {};
            user?.preferences['Diet']['IsVegan'] = isVegan.value;
          });

          userController.user.value.preferences['IsDairyFree'] =
              isDairyFree.value;
          userController.user.update((user) {
            user?.preferences['Diet'] ??= {};
            user?.preferences['Diet']['IsDairyFree'] = isDairyFree.value;
          });

          Get.off(() => const AllergyConfigurationScreen(),
              transition: Transition.rightToLeftWithFade);
          break;

// rest of the code
}
```

`firestore db structure:`

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXB4G.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting boolean from this response?

userController.user.value.preferences['diet']?['IsVegan']

Comment: I wasn't and I'm still figuring it out. Do you see the problem? @Md.KamrulAmin

Comment: If you are not getting boolean from the above value. You need to change isVegan type to RxString from RxBool. As you can not assign a string to a boolean. You can also add your firebase db structure here, so it is easier for others to see what type of values you are trying to fetch.
Print this value 'userController.user.value.preferences['diet']?['IsVegan']' . Check what value you are receiving from here. If you do not receive any value please use async/await to wait for the result to be retrieved from web.